# Calculating mean for class variables in python dataframe

Tags: python, class, mean

I have a dataframe of session log-in data. Each entry is associated with a class (e, c, g, m). So rows look like this:

```
1: [session_start_time  session_end_time    class_id    problems_completed  student_id  student_account_created student_previous_logins_total   student_previous_class_logins   duration]

2: [1/6/12 16:28    1/6/12 16:55    e   37  91  10/26/11 0:00   76  27  1/1/04 0:27]

3: [1/11/12 13:18   1/11/12 13:58   m   33  172 1/10/12 0:00    5   3   1/1/04 0:40]
```

I am trying to calculate the average "duration" for each class (e, c, g, etc.). I am having trouble finding the right command to calculate the average per class, rather than the mean of the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what data format/structure you
mean your source data is in, since what you present is not an exact Python representation. But let's assume your rows are 
lists of strings (or
can easily be converted into them):

```
rows = [
    [ '1/6/12 16:28', '1/6/12 16:55', 'e' ],
    [ '1/11/12 13:18', '1/11/12 13:58', 'm' ],
    [ '1/13/12 13:20', '1/13/12 13:24', 'm' ]
]
```

Then, here's one way to compute the mean by class:

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime

def parse(s, format="%x %H:%M"):
    """
    Return parsed datetime in the given format.
    """
    return datetime.strptime(s, format)

total_items = Counter()
total_duration = Counter()

for start, end, kind in rows:
    duration = parse(end) - parse(start)
    total_items[kind] += 1
    total_duration[kind] += duration.total_seconds()

means = { k: total_duration[k] / total_items[k] for k in total_items }
print means
```

This uses `collections.Counter`s to track both the count of each class in the log and the duration. Duration must be computed, first by parsing the date/time string representation into an internal format like `datetime.datetime`. Once the counters are accumulated, a dictionary comprehension computes the mean per kind (what you call 
"class" but that's a technical Python construct, so I call it a kind).

The resulting `means` stores the computed values. `means['m']` gives the mean for all of the `'m'` entries, and so forth.

While the `parse` function will work for the few data samples you showed in your question, date/time parsing is pretty finicky. Instead of using the `strptime` method here, I recommend using a more expansive and inclusive parser, such as that found in the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) module. If you wanted to use that, delete or rename the `parse` function found here, and substitute:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
```

That provides a drop-in replacement with a much broader range of accepted formats.